# How do I search "%" (percentage sign) in text using ILIKE operator in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, where-clause, sql-like

```
| id | text  |
|----|-------|
| 1  | AB    |
| 2  | CD%EF |
| 3  | GH    |
```

I have a text column in a table having a value with a "%" sign.

I wanted to extract that value using the following query —

```
SELECT text FORM table
WHERE text ILIKE '%%%'
```

expected Output should be:

```
CD%EF
1 {row}
```

actual output returns:

```
AB
CD%EF
GH
3 {rows}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `\%` to represent a *literal* percent sign:

```
SELECT text FORM table WHERE text ILIKE '%\%%'
```

Like [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE) says:

> To match a literal underscore or percent sign without matching other characters, the respective character in `pattern` must be preceded by the escape character. The default escape character is the backslash but a different one can be selected by using the `ESCAPE` clause. To match the escape character itself, write two escape characters.

Comment: Thanks you Laurenz Albe and @GMB, it solved my problem.